# Google Search with Regular Expressions

Tags: google-search, regex

Is it possible to use regular expressions or very simple regular expressions in google search?

Like search the term "`goog?e`", where the ? indicates a character or a number.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to do so.

Comment: To clarify: "Generally, punctuation is ignored, including @#$%^&*()=+[]\ and other special characters." ([source](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=134479&rd=1))

Answer (score -1):

Google does not recognize regular expressions, but [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) does.

#### Edit

... but this service no longer exists. I am leaving this answer here for posterity, however.

Comment: Obsolete: service has been shut down.